# Is there any way to get the whole IMDB review database?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am making a sentiment analysis project in python and for that I need to scrape the reviews for all movie and TV titles from IMDB. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow! Well, we're not going to write code for you. First write some code that has a specific problem, then ask about that specific problem here. Taking a look at this [question-checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) may probably help you to ask a good question.

Comment: Are you sure your computer has enough memory for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle is a good website to look for datasets -- some can be downloaded and others can be called through an API.

https://www.kaggle.com/ashirwadsangwan/imdb-dataset

Is this the dataset one you are looking for?